# Unable to start posgtresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have installed postgresql for a long time, but it suddenly stopped working when I added an IP address in the pg_hba file.

I'm trying to run it using `sudo service postgresql restart` but this doesn't work.
Also

```
root@ubuntu-dev-server:/# systemctl start postgresql@9.6-main
Job for postgresql@9.6-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status postgresql@9.6-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And then,

```
root@ubuntu-dev-server:/# systemctl status postgresql@9.6-main.service
● postgresql@9.6-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 9.6-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Fri 2020-07-24 16:56:06 UTC; 1min 54s ago
  Process: 31877 ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect -m fast 9.6-main stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 951 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 9.6-main start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 24944 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 24 16:56:06 ubuntu-dev-server systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 9.6-main...
Jul 24 16:56:06 ubuntu-dev-server postgresql@9.6-main[951]: The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
Jul 24 16:56:06 ubuntu-dev-server postgresql@9.6-main[951]: 2020-07-24 16:56:06.236 UTC [956] FATAL:  could not map anonymous shared memory: Cannot allocate memory
Jul 24 16:56:06 ubuntu-dev-server postgresql@9.6-main[951]: 2020-07-24 16:56:06.236 UTC [956] HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory, swap space, or huge pages. To reduce the request size (currently 148471808 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.
Jul 24 16:56:06 ubuntu-dev-server postgresql@9.6-main[951]: 2020-07-24 16:56:06.236 UTC [956] LOG:  database system is shut down
Jul 24 16:56:06 ubuntu-dev-server systemd[1]: postgresql@9.6-main.service: Can't open PID file /run/postgresql/9.6-main.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Jul 24 16:56:06 ubuntu-dev-server systemd[1]: postgresql@9.6-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Jul 24 16:56:06 ubuntu-dev-server systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 9.6-main.
```

I have tried several things but still do not start. Any recommendation is welcome.

Comment: What did you try? The error that is stopping this is: "FATAL:  could not map anonymous shared memory: Cannot allocate memory".  Did try the suggestions in the ```HINT:```? Have you looked in the Postgres and system logs?

Comment: Thanks, based in the `HINT:` the solution was add `Swap` space in the server. I followed this useful tutorial. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04